# MongoDB "E11000 duplicate key error index" after rebuilding DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

This is really strange. Recently one of my MongoDB servers went down and as a result I tried to reboot. Nothing seems to work -- just keep getting this same error as soon as I try to enter a new record (and the DB even reports 0 records before I tried this).

So I decided just to move all the old /data files and re-create everything from more or less from scratch.

I have one server running mongos, 3 servers running mongod --configsvr, and 2 running mongod --shardsvr. Everything is setup correctly, I'm certain, and it did work before that server crashed the other day.

I was thinking that deleting *all* the MongoDB /data files would've caused any old indexes to clear themselves out? How can I still be getting a unique key collision? It makes no sense.

Even stranger is that, after trying to add the first record, it *does* create a record, but that record has empty attributes, and trying to save that record results in the same key error.

If it matters at all, I'm using Ruby/Rails for this project. I imagine this is more of a MongoDB issue, though.

Comment: can you show the output of `db.collections.getIndexes()` on the collection where you're seeing the error?

Comment: Have you tried to add a record manually? From your description, I assume that you are generating an `_id` within your code. Seems like the IDs generated are prone to duplicates. Maybe an increment counter or sth?